# Phone does not use SD card

Tags: sd-card, storage

I have a Lenovo A526. In storage settings I've selected SD Card as the "Default Write Disk".

The phone storage is 2gb and I have ~150 MB available, whereas the SD card is nearly 15GB and has most of that available.

The problem is that when I attempt to download any app, I get an error saying that there is not enough space available and I should make some room.

Why is this happening? There's plenty of room if the phone simply decided to use the SD card.

How can I make it use the SD card instead of always using the smaller (and full) phone storage?

Comment: Some (few) apps can be installed / moved to sd card. Most require to be installed onto phone storage. Have a look in settings/applications which apps have the move to sd card button active. Also you can set default storage for photos in the camera app.

Comment: what! that's ridiculous!

Comment: See related Q/A in the tag [tag:insufficient-memory].

Comment: @Aequitas it seems but it's not, apps on sd card do not have the same permissions that those installed on phone storage. Else you could just put an sd card into another phone an mess with it.

Comment: @Dan it is because 2gb is very limited, especially when a good portion of it is filled with uninstallable google apps like maps, drive, G+, Chrome and play services!

Comment: Nowadays anything less then quad  core with 1gb ram and 8gb storage is not going to be usable. For rooted phones there is a thing called ext2sd, that extends internal storage onto a sd partition.